# Angular/ MongoDB/ NodeJs: Auto login from one domain to another domain

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, jwt

In my application I am managing two domains; one is `http://localhost:4500` and other on `http://localhost:4600`

Now the scenario is when logged in to the `http://localhost:4500` domain using those credentials I also want to make an implementation that will auto login to the `http://localhost:4600` domain while clicked on the `got-to-front-panel` link  for that particular user who has logged in to the http://localhost:4500 domain.

For `http://localhost:4500` domain I have an Angular application for that I have managed with `externalUrl` routing process.

app-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: "go-to-front-panel",
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard],
    component: RedirectGuard,
    data: {
      externalUrl: "http://localhost:4600"
    }
}
```

redirect-guard.service.ts

```
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate({ data }: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    window.open(data.externalUrl, '_blank');
    return false;
  }
}
```

While login into the `http://localhost:4500` domain it stores the below json values into mongodb table

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb088781f14e2f783eq262"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "token" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImp0aSI6IjM4Njk4NWUyLTc5MTItNDZhMy04YjY5LWMxYTdhZDQ2OWRhMSIsImlhdCI6MTYwNzQxMDMxMSwiZXhwIjoxNjA3NDEzOTExfQ.0czxMiH7yblJWxIepzHbq7C8oVde01kFnKnScC54LW4",
    "createdAt" : "2020-11-08 15:00:55",
    "deactivatedAt" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and in the sessionStorage it stores the token value of this domain `http://localhost:4500`

login.component.ts

`sessionStorage.setItem('token', userDetails.token);`

=> Token value is generated using `jwt.sign` method as below.

```
const token = jwt.sign({ userDetails }, SECRET_KEY);
```

=> So how can I manage to auto login from `http://localhost:4500` domain to `http://localhost:4600` domain

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say it's auto login.

But when you click on `got-to-front-panel`, you can try to follow the following procedure.

(1) Fetch backend for a nonce. The nonce will be able to identify the user. You may save the nonce in redis or something which expires in 5-10 seconds.

(2) append the nonce to http://localhost:4600?/nonce=some-very-long-unique-string-like-uuid

(3) http://localhost:4600 contact backend with the nonce to authenticate. Backend expires the nonce and response with a authentication token.

(4) http://localhost:4600 gets the authentication token and save it to localstorage

This behavior is similar to how you do authentication in google/facebook and redirect to your desire url with unique code for authentication.

**The other method is somehow similar.**

(1) User login http://localhost:4700, get authentication token

(2) User redirected to http://localhost:4800/redirect-url/?token=sometoken

(3) complete authentication at http://localhost:4800 by saving the token in localstorage or with your own authentication mechanism

(4) redirect back to http://localhost:4700

(5) viola, saved login on both domains.

Answer (score 0):

Since different localhost ports are considered as different domains, one cannot access other's resources like cookies or localStorage.

If those two apps would be deployed in the sub-directories of the same domain during production (company.com/app1 and company.com/app2), one can access another's resource and auto login would work without any issue.

(This is my exact situation and I have 4 different angular apps that use the same login data. As they are in the same domain and on the business trust established among them, when the user logs in to one app, other apps when opened will automatically log him in using the same localStorage data and upon expiry any one will renew the token and others will use the same new token)

Else, you can achieve this using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) api.

i.e, you can have a (hidden) iframe in the 4600's app and when it is opened, it may load 4500 in the iframe and with the appropriate handler written in 4500, 4600 can make a request using postMessage api and 4500 can send the login data present in it. This can be implemented without using iframes by exchanging data
between a popup and its parent like

```
window.parent.postMessage()
```

Please note, I am unable to share the example code or the links to the apps as they are proprietary and not publicly available.